# Custom TableView issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a  custom header view in my iphone app. and it have a custom button over that.
But that custom button action is not fire but header tap event is fired which is in custom class .Please help me .How to fire action on button in header view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:section];
    UIView * customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)]autorelease];
    customView.tag = section;
    [customView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(260, 7, 25, 25);
    button.tag=section;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(expandCollapsing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setSelected:YES];

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, so that we can help you out?

Comment: Hey just replace the snippet I posted recently. It will solve your problem of clicking, even you need not to use custom view or Gesture too.

Comment: You have missed the part in your code where you return the view, or add the button to the customView as a subview. I assume this is just missing from the question rather than from your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own callback method to do this.

**What i did is** I added a TapGesture to the customView. When the event is fired i used a callback method to pass the control to the viewController where my tableView is implemeted

**What you can do** While loading the header you can assign the tag value to the customView

```
customHeader.tag = 1;
```

and you can implement the call back method in your viewController.

In CustomheaderView

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxEventHandler:)];
  [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
  [self setGestureRecognizers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:recognizer]];


-(IBAction)checkBoxEventHandler:(id)sender
{
     if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedHeader: atIndex:)]) 
     {
            [self.delegate selectedHeader:self atIndex:self.tag];
     }
}

In your viewController.m
-(void)selectedHeader:(myCustomHeader *)header atIndex:(int)index
{
   //header -> will give you the same instance you created in your viewController while loading this custom header view
   // So you can check the tag like this
   if(header.tag == 1) 
   { 
      //Do Stuff here
   }

   // index -> we are passing headerViews tag as index ie header.tag is equal to index
   // So checking the tag like this is the proper way
   if(index == 1) 
   { 
      //Do Stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: but problem is that i need to pass dynamic button tag.how i will do the same thing with UITapgestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this code will solve your problem :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{   
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 25, 25);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag=section;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(expandCollapsing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setSelected:YES];
    return button;

}
-(void)expandCollapsing:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag:%d",[btn tag]);
}
```